# why is this MutationObserver not observing any mutations?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, mutation-observers

I'm doing this inside a GreaseMonkey script in Firefox. I'm trying to detect new child divs being added, via Ajax, I assume, this page is not my own. It's a chat/collaboration app like Discord or Slack. I copied this pattern from the MutationObserver docs on MDN. Here's the relevant bits:

```
function findNewMessages() {
  console.log("findNewMessages");
  
  // Select the node that will be observed for mutations
  const targetNode = document.getElementsByClassName("scrollerInner-2YIMLh");
  if(targetNode) {
        console.log("findNewMessages::found scrollerInner");
  }
  
  // Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
    const config = { childList: true, subtree: true };
  
  // Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
  const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
      
      for(const mutation of mutationsList) {
          if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
              console.log('findNewMessages:: A child node has been added or removed.');
          }
          else {
            console.log("findNewMessages:: mutation : " + JSON.stringify(mutation));
          }
      }
  };

  // Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
  const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
  
  // Start observing the target node for configured mutations
  observer.observe(targetNode, config);

  // Later, you can stop observing
//   observer.disconnect();
}

// delay for page to load; 
// tried @run-at      document-idle in the header but it wasn't working
setTimeout(findNewMessages, 10000);
```

The targetNode is being found and it is the right one. I typed in a message and watched a new child element being added, but the mutation observer didn't fire.

Based on questions here, I found another form which I tried:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    for(const mutation of mutationsList) {
      if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
        console.log('findNewMessages:: A child node has been added or removed.');
      }
      else {
        console.log("findNewMessages:: mutation : " + JSON.stringify(mutation));
      }
    }
  });
```

Same results, no mutations.
I also tried using the [MutationSummary library](https://github.com/rafaelw/mutation-summary), found in another answer, but had same problem. My javascript and selector syntax is pretty rusty; am I missing anything obvious?

Comment: Your console should be complaining about the first argument passed to MutationObserver.observe not being a Node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName("scrollerInner-2YIMLh");`

returns html collection of elements

the 1st parameter of `observer.observe()` accepts a specific element not a collection.
So you have to use `getElementById`.

Otherwise you may use a `for` loop to iterate your `targetNode` variable.